# Unwrapping UV island to fit a 2D shape

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

As in the GIF, I try to fit that UV island in the shape which I marked with blue color. I pin the vertices that I drag to make other vertices drag accordingly. However it acts very weirdly as in the GIF? How can I fit that UV island easily in the shape without working on every node?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! The first thing that comes to mind for me would be to manually move all the outer edges into place around your shape, pin all the outer edges (not just the corners), then unwrap your mesh again. This will keep all the pinned UVs, and unwrap the rest accordingly. Would this work or were you hoping for something simpler?

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thank you :)